# Unity Tweak Tool is giving an error: com.canonical.notify-osd

Tags: unity, notify-osd, unity-tweak-tool

I just installed Unity Tweak Tool but haven't been able to use it due to the error it keeps giving, which is: com.canonical.notify-osd

I tried looking it up but haven't come up with anything so far. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the actual error says: "Following schema is missing  com.canonical.notify-osd " thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity Tweak Tool Schema Missing com.canonical.desktop.interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965583/unity-tweak-tool-schema-missing-com-canonical-desktop-interface)

Answer (score 7):

Go to a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall notify-osd
sudo apt-get install --reinstall overlay-scrollbar
```

This will install 2 packages if you don't have them or re-install them if already present and broken.

Answer (score 5):

use Synaptics and search for `notify-osd` .Install it .

Your Issue will be fixed.

Comment: Thank you, really helped. I used next commands:

1) sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 2)  sudo apt-get update 3)   sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig

Answer (score 1):

Simply updating the notify-osd may lead to you getting an additional error The following Schema is missing: `com.canonical.desktop.interface`.

The solution to this should be to:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-service
```

Though the background to this could be dependency issues. If so the command line could give a suggestion like try:

```
apt-get -f install
```

in which case you will want to:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and this could well resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. The following commands helped me,

```
sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install notify-osd
```