# Unity Tweak Tool Schema Missing com.canonical.desktop.interface

Tags: unity, notify-osd, unity-tweak-tool

Running Unity on fresh install of 14.04. I installed Unity Tweak Tool through the Software Center, and on initial launch it said:

> The following schema is missing
>
> ```
> com.canonical.notify.osd
> ```
>
> In order to work properly, Unity Tweak Tool recommends you install the necessary packages.

So in the terminal I used

```
sudo apt-get install notify-osd
```

Then, when I tried to open Unity Tweak Tool again, I got the same message but instead of `com.canonical.notify.osd`, it's saying `com.canonical.desktop.interface` is missing. How do I get this to run?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I had the same issue, and I used the above solutions. Both were required to achieve a solution.

```
sudo apt-get install notify-osd
sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar
```

Now it works perfectly.

Comment: One line: `sudo apt-get install notify-osd overlay-scrollbar`

Answer (score 4):

Used

```
sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar
```

Works now.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, I had this issue on 18.04 and it was solved only by running

```
sudo apt install notify-osd
```

I didn't need to install overlay-scrollbar.