# Error: schema com.canonical.notify-osd not installed

Tags: unity, unity-tweak-tool

I installed unity-tweak-tool

```
gaowei@alpha:~$ which unity-tweak-tool
/usr/bin/unity-tweak-tool
```

When I try to run, it prompts

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UnityTweakTool/__init__.py:40: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
Error: schema com.canonical.notify-osd not installed
```

[image: GUI variant of above error]

I tried to install the schema:

```
gaowei@alpha:~$ sudo apt-get install com.canonical.notify-osd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package com.canonical.notify-osd
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'com.canonical.notify-osd'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'com.canonical.notify-osd'
```

How could I continue on this mission?

Comment: You can try this solution.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/965583/unity-tweak-tool-schema-missing-com-canonical-desktop-interface/965602 Best Regards,
Jay Wang.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different package missing but I fixed it with this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-tweak-tool/+bug/1845737

Try to see if that `notify-osd` goes by a different name.